# C++ function that returns a pointer to an abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class

Does it make sense for a function to return a pointer to an abstract class?

Comment: Of course. A class factory, for example, will usually do that.

Comment: For example if you have an std::vector<Base*> member, and a Get function which is give back a Base*... Base can be abstract... so basically, when you use polymorphism or pimpl idiom it makes sense

Comment: @Melkon: How is pimpl relevant in this context?

Comment: That is, of course, a pointer pointing to an *object* of a *derived* class, which is *of the type* pointer-to-abstract-class... because you cannot have *objects* of abstract class.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: In this case you store a Base* pointer, unfortunetaly i saw cases when it was return through a getter. :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course, that's the whole point of polymorphism : to pass around and use pointers to abstract classes, regardless of what the concrete implementation is.

Among others, the Factory Pattern typically returns a pointer to an abstract class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it makes sense to manipulate pointer (or reference) to an abstract class in order to decouple the interface from the actual implementation and exploit the benefits of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

But note that if the function is in charge of allocating the returned object (some kind of [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)), make sure to use a virtual destructor to be able to correctly delete the object from the abstract class pointer :

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    ~Derived() override {
        // Do some important cleanup
    }
};

Base* factory() {
    return new Derived;
}

Base* base = factory();
base->~Base(); // calls Derived::~Derived
```

Without the virtual destructor's of `Base`, the destructor of `Derived` would not have been called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does make sense.
 It's like using interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. Say you have an abstract class named `AClass`, with a concrete implementation called `CClass`. You could return a pointer to an instance of `CClass` which could be of type `AClass*` or `CClass*`. However, as you can't instantiate an abstract class, you can't return a pointer to an *instance* of an abstract class.

However, if you return `AClass*`, your client will only be able to access the interface of `AClass`; if they want to access `CClass` functionality not included in the interface of `AClass`, they will need to cast the pointer to be `CClass*`.